# Applications on derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, functional-calculus

Show that the tangents to the curve $y=2x^{3}-2$ at $x=2$ and at $x=-2$ are parallel.
I try to solve this but not getting how to start . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Think about what it means for two lines on a graph to be parallel, think about the first line as $y_1=a_1x+b_1$ and the second as $y_2=a_2x+b_2$. Now, what should the parameters look like for the lines to be parallels? And in second instance, how would you find the equations for the tangent lines for the curve you gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the derivative of the curve, $\frac{dy}{dx} = 6x^2$.
For $x=2$, the slope of the curve is equal to $24$.
For $x=-2$ the slope of the curve is also equal to $24$.
Hence, the tangents on the curve will have the same slope on $x=2$ and $x=-2$. Conclusion: The tangents are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

For tangents to be parallel, their slopes should be equal.

Let $f(x)=2x^3-2$

$$f'(x)=6x^2$$
Now, slope of a tangent at a point on curve $= f'(x)$
You can put the values of $x$ as $+2$ and $-2$ to verify your answer

Comment: Thanks for helping me to everyone.

Comment: @user197636 If you liked the answer, you can hit the tick arrow next to the answer